# Spread sheet if a cell is true make others false

Tags: google-sheets

I want a spread sheet to look at the values of tree cells and if I make A1 true make B1 and C1 false. But if I change B1 to true than A1 and C1 goes false and same for C1. I'm not sure how to make it or even if it's possible.

It's supposed to be used for a system to keep track of whether people are inside building1, building2 or outside.

Comment: I think this is more for web applications stack

Comment: This question belongs on the Webapps site.

Answer (score 1):

You can definitely make one cell dependent on another, like so:

```
 =IF(A1=TRUE, "FALSE", "TRUE")
```

But you want the option to hardcode any one of three cells and have the other two respond. AFAIK, you can't a formula in a cell and sometimes hardcode it.

How about having a fourth column in which you write the value of which building the person is in, and have all three other cells contain formulae based off of the value of the fourth column, like so:

Column A represents which building the person is in. This is where you can hardcode the value.

Column B says true/false whether the person is in Building1: `=IF(A1="building1", "TRUE", "FALSE")

Column C says true/false whether the person is in Building2: `=IF(A1="building2", "TRUE", "FALSE")

Column D says true/false whether the person is in Building3: `=IF(A1="building3", "TRUE", "FALSE")

So it ends up looking like

```
 A             B           C          D
 building1     TRUE        FALSE      FALSE
 building3     FALSE       FALSE      FALSE
 building84    FALSE       FALSE      FALSE
```